# query on reports for filtering on basis of coloum name

Tags: custom-report-type

I would like to know how can i know the Account.Owner field used in how many reports in salesforce. Is there any query possible like

```
Select id,name from report where coloum.name=account.owner
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get some Report Metadata, there's an API for that.

Hope this two links point you in the right direction:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportmetadata.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have to use any IDE that could retrieve Reports metadata (e.g. Eclipse, MavensMate) and then you can do 'Find in Files' as with any txt files search